# Spring Boot class Size not found @Size(min=1,max=18)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have a `User` class as below and I am trying to enforce validation and I am getting an:

> error cannot find symbol symbol:   class Size

My class looks something like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private long id;
    @Size(min=1,max=18)
    private int age;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Well .... how about importing the annotation?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an import for the size annotation.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
```

Answer (score 2):

Most people are doing the quick answer which is "did you import" but I am guessing you are a semi-intelligent developer and would understand how to import a class. My guess is that the class isn't on the classpath and as such your IDE can't figure out how to import the annotation. This is because the annotation is part of J6EE which isn't in the JDK. They have made the validation annotations their own library called [validation-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api). It is currently at version 1.1.0. To make it easier than using that library you should really look at using the [hibernate-validator library](http://hibernate.org/validator/) as it will include that api library along with the proper implemented classes to actually validate beans.

Example of how to do validation is in a [Getting Started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/).

Comment: So you assume that OP imported it correctly, but removed that statement from his code and left the other imports behind? Would be really strange, don't you think?